# How can I insert an image into a question/answer of a Javascript quiz?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a quiz and would like it to be based on images as questions or responses (whatever can work) - for example, the user is asked 'What animal is this' and should choose the button 'cat' after seeing an image of a cat.

I have tried putting an image tag into my HTML buttons but they do not show up in my preview.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <!Set up divs of container to hold all, questions to store and present questions and buttons of possible answers>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="question-container" class="hide">
      <div id="question">Question</div>
      <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn"><img src="Images/1Cat.png" width="224" height="174" alt="Cat"></button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!Set up start and next buttons>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
      <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
const questions = [
  {
    question: 'Which is a CAT?',
    answers: [
      { text: ' ', correct: true },
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: ' ', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Which is a SEAHORSE?',
    answers: [
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: ' ', correct: true },
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: 'Fun Fun Function', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Which is a LION?',
    answers: [
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: ' ', correct: true }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Which is a DEER?',
    answers: [
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: ' ', correct: false },
      { text: ' ', correct: false }
    ]
  }
]
```

Have been trying to figure this one out for a while, would appreciate some help :)

Comment: try an `input type="image"` instead of a button

Comment: Actually, you should be able to put an `<img>` inside a `<button>` with no problems.
can you add a snippet so we can figure what's the problem?

Comment: Absolutely - a snippet of what?

Comment: @code2021 a snippet of the button that you want to insert an image inside it

Comment: In my HTML example those four buttons are where I want the images to be ideally - did you mean an image? Sorry I'm not very experienced at coding, this is confusing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

```js
const questions = [{
    question: 'Which is a CAT?',
    answers: [{
        text: ' ',
        correct: true
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Which is a SEAHORSE?',
    answers: [{
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: true
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Fun Fun Function',
        correct: false
      }
    ]
  }
]

//If you use jQuery:
function checkAns(selectedOption) {
  if (questions[0].answers[+$(selectedOption).data("option")].correct == true) {
    alert("Correct Answer!");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
  }
}
```

```css
.option-image {
  width: 100px;
  outline-style: ridge;
  outline-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="question-container" class="hide">
      <div id="question">Which is cat?</div>
      <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <img class="option-image" data-option="0" onclick="checkAns(this)" src="https://freepngimg.com/thumb/cat/10-2-cat-png-9.png" />
        <img class="option-image" data-option="1" onclick="checkAns(this)" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/dog/dog_PNG50348.png" />
        <img class="option-image" data-option="2" onclick="checkAns(this)" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/GTItesdrRG4uRYC9vihgQTk4J-AYL_ckCu_DeHnn-E--Gqld09lkH9Nwi4O7L28ga5a9DtpUaYVga-3fHnBF9pdvjuGX67v3yAYbWGDfJ81VLyrsSNktW78aNtM" />
        <img class="option-image" data-option="3" onclick="checkAns(this)" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/donkey/donkey_PNG5.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
      <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

<!-- Inserted Images may contain copyright claims. Used for educational Purposes. Fetched from GOOGLE.COM -->
```

As you asked, for Dreamweaver:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.option-image {
  width: 100px;
  outline-style: ridge;
  outline-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="question-container" class="hide">
      <div id="question">Which is cat?</div>
      <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <img class="option-image" data-option="0" onclick="checkAns(this)" src="https://freepngimg.com/thumb/cat/10-2-cat-png-9.png" />
        <img class="option-image" data-option="1" onclick="checkAns(this)" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/dog/dog_PNG50348.png" />
        <img class="option-image" data-option="2" onclick="checkAns(this)" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/GTItesdrRG4uRYC9vihgQTk4J-AYL_ckCu_DeHnn-E--Gqld09lkH9Nwi4O7L28ga5a9DtpUaYVga-3fHnBF9pdvjuGX67v3yAYbWGDfJ81VLyrsSNktW78aNtM" />
        <img class="option-image" data-option="3" onclick="checkAns(this)" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/donkey/donkey_PNG5.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!Set up start and next buttons>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
      <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
const questions = [{
    question: 'Which is a CAT?',
    answers: [{
        text: ' ',
        correct: true
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Which is a SEAHORSE?',
    answers: [{
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: true
      },
      {
        text: ' ',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Fun Fun Function',
        correct: false
      }
    ]
  }
]

//If you use jQuery:
function checkAns(selectedOption) {
  if (questions[0].answers[+$(selectedOption).data("option")].correct == true) {
    alert("Correct Answer!");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
  }
}
</script>
</body>

<!-- Inserted Images may contain copyright claims. Used for educational Purposes. Fetched from GOOGLE.COM -->
</html>
```

Comment: Ok so this looks like it would add my images but it also means that the buttons don't work - it's probably because I put your JS in the place of all of my original JS, so should I just be substituting this for a certain section?

Comment: I modified it check it again

Comment: I've not made the start and next buttons functional

Comment: Requesting you to Accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Yes! This works on the view code snippet in my stack overflow window but not when I copy the code into Dreamweaver and then preview in chrome? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Yes. You actually need to properly write `<body>` tags, `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` and also import the jQuery Library by using the script tag. In StackOverflow it automatically does it so that I can spend time helping you out instead of writing every detail of the code

Comment: I'll modify it to make it work with dreamweaver

Comment: Ok - on my document I have a different script link tag to my own JS document, do I then also need to use your script tag to get JQuery? Not sure I understand how to import jQuery... Thanks again for helping

Comment: I've modified it